# Multithreading with async fuinctions to create new task, that do not wait other running task with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a several tools that every user can use it and I wrote them with python language. I worked with RabbitMQ message broker to get request from user and then start the task.So when each user send, request to server, the server handle all of incoming tasks in one loop (thread) as async and then wait all heavy process in program and do not listen for other message until the last job done.
My all tools yield result (generator functions) and then push them to queue (rabbitmq).
How can I run new thread (new task) that send results of tool's to user and do not wait all the tasks?

This is for async and multitask programming with python

Class WorkerProxy:

```
.
.
.
async def create_proccess(self, inputs):

        exchange, message = inputs

        data = dict()
        data['Result'] = json.dumps({"Status": '[+] Operation start'})
        data['Timestamp'] = str(datetime.now())
        data['Level'] = 'information'

        message_pack = json.loads(str(message.body.decode()))

        await self.send_message(
            str(json.dumps(data)), exchange, message.correlation_id,
            message.reply_to
        )

        for result in select_tool(message_pack):
            await self.send_message(
                str(result), exchange,
                message.correlation_id, message.reply_to
            )

        data['Result'] = json.dumps(
            {"Status": '[+] Operation done successfully'}
        )
        data['Timestamp'] = str(datetime.now())
        data['Level'] = 'information'

        await self.send_message(
            str(json.dumps(data)), exchange, message.correlation_id,
            message.reply_to
        )

    async def send_message(
        self, message: str, exchange,
        correlation_id, reply_to
    ):
        await exchange.publish(
            Message(
                body=message.encode(),
                correlation_id=correlation_id
            ),
            routing_key=reply_to
        )

    async def on_message(self, exchange: Exchange, message: IncomingMessage):

        ''' TODO => here we must build rpc_server for
            each client and create specific queue for them
        '''

        with message.process():
            # print("[X] Received message: %r" % message)
            print("=> Message: %r" % message.body)

            asyncio.ensure_future(self.create_proccess((exchange, message)))

.
.
.
```

I expect that, when each message recevied from queue the server will create new parallel thread with others, to send tool's result as response message to user

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create some number of threads and one query for each thread.

You can use [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module for creating threads (can be a class derived from `Thread` with `run()` method, or simple wrapper around your function), and [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) for queues.

very basic example:

```py
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def my_function(q):
    print q.get() # or whatever

q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=my_function, args=(q,))
t.start()
```

Now `my_function` will be executed in separate thread and will have access to that queue. When function execution is done, thread will be closed as well, so you'll have to implement some waiting loop.